# Как добавить текст из полей input в textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Столкнулся с проблемой вроде все просто, но что-то не получается. Мой вариант:

```
$('#btn_help').click(function () 
{
    var text = $('#notify_message_email').value
    $('#notify_message_message').value += text;
});

$('#btn_help').click(function () 
{
    var text = $('#notify_message_email').value
    $('#notify_message_message').append(text);
});
```

на ни один из них не работает, как написать правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В JQuery используйте [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$('#btn_help').click(function () {
var text = $('#notify_message_email').val()
$('#notify_message_message').val( $('#notify_message_message').val() + text);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Возможно в данном варианте стоит почитать документацию.

Comment: Наш сайт отличается от социальных сетей. Он помогает решать прикладные задачи. Поэтому мы используем комментарии только по делу — уточнить проблему, дать конструктивную критику или добавить полезную информацию. Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers